# Cannot read dicom image

Tags: python, image-processing, pydicom

I tried to read Dicom image, but there is a problem which is `cannot reshape array of size 129024 into shape (576,448)`

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydicom
filename = 'data/train/IM-0001-0001.dcm'
ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think one of your *Rows* or *Columns* values are wrong. 576 x 448 doesn't equal 129024 pixels. Try setting `ds.Columns = 224` or `ds.Rows = 288` before calling `ds.pixel_array`.

Comment: @scaramallion I solved it. Thank you

Comment: That's great. Please add the solution and mark the question as answered